# python loop io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Tags: python, loops

I am getting the following error when trying to output to a text file:
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Any help appreciated. thanks

```
f = open("google-searches.txt", "w+")
for item in results:
    google_searches.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: Did you mean `File or stream is not writable` perhaps?

Comment: And why are you writing to `google_searches` while you opened `f`? What is `google_searches` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you're writing to the wrong file.

You have opened `f`, so you should **write** to `f`, not to `google_searches`:

```
f = open("google-searches.txt", "w+")
for item in results:
    f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: @SteveBarrett if this answer helped you, would you mind accepting it by clicking on the green check next to my answer? **It gives you reputation too!**

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
f = open("google-searches.txt", "w+")
for item in results:
    f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

because your opened file object is `f`.